# 'fetch' in PDO gets only one result

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have this code:

```
$sql = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=b', 'root', 'root');
$f = $sql->query('select * from user');
$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $f->fetch()){
     print_r($row);
}
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => turki
    [mail] => ablaf
    [pass] => 144
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => wrfwer
    [mail] => fwerf
    [pass] => werf
)
```

And that's what I really want. But if I do this

```
<?php
    $sql = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=b', 'root', 'root');
    $f = $sql->query('select * from user');
    $f->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($f->fetch());
?>
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => turki
    [mail] => ablaf
    [pass] => 144
)
```

It has one result, but I have two rows in the table; why is that?

Comment: fetch used to be fetch one row at a time. You may use fetch in loop or user fetchAll like other say to get all rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fetch should be used to display the next row from the database result.

To get all rows, you should use [fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php);

- [PDOStatement::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) — Fetches the next row from a result set
- [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows

Change your example to:

```
<?php
    $sql = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=b', 'root', 'root');
    $f = $sql->query('select * from user');
    $f->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($f->fetchAll());
?>
```

or if you want use [PDOStatement::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) to

```
<?php
    $sql = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=b', 'root', 'root');
    $sth = $sql->query('select * from user');
    while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      print_r($row);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have we got some bad copy-pasta here?  I don't see where you've defined `$sth`.  If there are no variables to bind to the statement, then a prepared statement is unnecessary overhead.

Comment: not sure what you meant by prepared statements as this answer clearly doesn't mention it but you were right with $sth it was a typo.

Comment: Now, IMO,  `sth` is misleading.  The return from the query isn't a "statement handle" -- it is a result set resource/object.  `sth` would be more appropriate when using a prepared statement.  Your hyperlinks are pointing to prepared statement documentation, but your snippet is not using a prepared statement.

Answer (score 2):

In that case use [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

```
$result = $f->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

*[PDOStatement::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)* only retrieves one record from a *PDOStatement* object (wherever its pointer is) which is why you have to loop through *fetch*.

Answer (score 0):

The [fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method only returns a single record and sets the internal pointer to point to the next record. You are expecting from this method what it cannot return.

Perhaps try a different method like [fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

```
<?php
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
    $sth->execute();

    /* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
    print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$f->fetch()` moves the internal result pointer to the next value (if it exists). That’s why you get all the values when you call it in `while();`.

Answer (score 0):

`$f->fetch()` - Will get **one** row

`$f->fetchAll()` - Will get **all** rows