# php - foreach loop only runs one

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, pdo, foreach

I have this foreach loop:

```
$d=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_rented WHERE since <= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 14 day) AND clicks_last <= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 14 day)");
    $d->execute();
        $array = array();
        foreach ($d as $data ) {
                 $array[] = $data['id'];
                     #print_r($new_array);
                     $userToRecycleFor = $data['user_by'];

                    $outcome =  $rentedrefs->_recycleMulti(0, $userToRecycleFor, $array, 1);


        }
```

The `$d` query has 2406 results when I run it in the MySQL database.

The `foreach` loop is only being run 1 time on every page refresh. So instead of updating all 2406 users (as per the SQL query), it updates only 1 per refresh.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should fetch the result. Somebody had exactly the same question as you -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916036/fetch-in-pdo-gets-only-one-result

Comment: you are looking for `PDO::fetch` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to fetch the data before looping

```
$result = $d->fetchAll();

foreach ($result  as $data ) {
   $userToRecycleFor = $data['user_by'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to fetch the result before loop over it. Try to change these lines:

```
$d->execute();

$array = array();

$rows = $d->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $data) {
     $array[] = $data['id'];
     $userToRecycleFor = $data['user_by'];

     $outcome =  $rentedrefs->_recycleMulti(0, $userToRecycleFor, $array, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you fetch results like this: (e.g. mysqli)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB);
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, name, store FROM food");

while($array = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
   $finalArray = $array;
}

foreach($finalArray as $item)
{
   // your process
}
```